# If you learn 한국어, do you need to learn 한자?

Tags: hanja

I don't know should I learn korean 한자 or not, because someone says there are more than half vocabulary from Chinese.
I already master Chinese, but Chinese 한자 and korean 한자 is different in terms of pronouciation, so I should systematically learn 한자?
Do you learn 한자?

Comment: In Korean, you don’t need to know how to read or write the actual Hanja characters. All you got to know is their Korean pronunciations.

Comment: 한자 is not necessary in common life even in Korea. I am a native Korean speaker born in 20th century. When I was teenager(Latte is horse(meme)), 한자 was used very widely, in newspapers, in books, on TV. All students studied 한자 at school. with my friends, we usually use 한자 to clarify 동음이의어 as 정의(定意) and 정의(正義).   But  nowadays, we can see 한자 very rarely. Students and teachers don't think 한자 is important, so they do not study 한자 at school.  young students use English to clarify 동음이의어 as 정의(definition) and 정의(justice).

Comment: We do not learn LATIN but we use LATIN WORDs, like "PERSONA NON GRATA", "Deus ex machina",  "Q.E.D.", "R.I.P.".  We can use "Q.E.D" to declare the end of proof without knowledge  LATINs nor "Quod Erat Demonstrandum".  Likewise, we can use 천고마비의 계절 to say autumn without knowledge of 한자 nor "天高馬肥의 季節"

Answer (score 3):

In my option it is useful to learn the meaning of certain syllables. It is a quick way to speed up your vocabulary acquisition once you get to a certain point.
For example, if you learn 자 means letter, then remembering or memorizing 글자, 문자, 숫자, 자막, 자판, 한자 becomes way easier.

However, you do not need to memorize 자 as 字 itself (how to write/read it), since you won't usually come across Chinese characters except in very specific circumstances. Many Koreans don't know them or they know only a few of them.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know Chinese very well, but we know the the feeling about meaning of Chinese words.

For example,

The word "일기" consists of "일" for a day and "기" for a record.

The work "필기" consists of "필" for a write and "기" for a record.

"일기" is chinese word and almost of people don't know how to write "일기" in chinese but we know "기" means kind of record something. If you know it, it's easy to study the word "기록"(means recording) because it's same "기"

When words that we don't use a lot in real life come out in books or news, we understand words better through these Chinese character meanings even though I don't know how to write it.

I don't think you need to study Chinese separately, but I think it'll be very helpful to study Korean if you think these meanings of the hangul.